# Context Free Grammar productions with alignment

Tags: align, syntax

I am trying to write grammar productions for a document. I am using align environment to get the desired grammar productions as follows:

```
\begin{align*} 
S\# &\rightarrow aA | bA\\ 
A\# &\rightarrow aA | bA\\
\# A &\rightarrow Aa | Ab \\
{A \above 0pt \#} &\rightarrow {a \above 0pt A} \mid {b \above 0pt A} \\
A &\rightarrow a | b
\end{align*}
```

But 
1. is there any better way to do that?
2. What can I do to get grammar productions with symbols one above the other? presently I am using ${a \above b}$ to achieve that. Is there a better way to do that?
3. I need productions of the form mentioned in the picture attached with one set of production adjacent to other. How to produce such grammar productions in `\LaTeX`?

Please help. I couldn't find any posts related to such issue. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't claim this is the best approach, but when I've typeset CFGs in the past, I tend to use `\to` and define an `\OR` macro for the separators. I've also replaced your `\above` with a new macro `\stack` that uses `\genfrac` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\OR{\ |\ }
\newcommand*\stack[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
S\# &\to aA \OR bA\\
A\# &\to aA \OR bA\\
\# A &\to Aa \OR Ab \\
\stack A\# &\to \stack aA \OR \stack bA \\
A &\to a \OR b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I should point out that a LaTeX purist would object to `\stack aA` and would instead write `\stack{a}{A}`. (And probably `\newcommand*{\OR}{\ |\ }`.) I tend to be less fussy about such things.

Answer (score 2):

`\above` is a way to stack letters / words. But since these formula look like arrays and only contain one symbol in each cell, why not use the `array`-environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  \hphantom{\#} & \# & \# \\
                & S  & \# \\
  &\#
  \end{array}
  &\rightarrow
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  \hphantom{\#} & \# & \# \\
                & a  & S  \\
  &S
  \end{array}
  \\
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  \\
  \#            & S  & S  \\
  & \#
  \end{array}
  &\rightarrow
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  \\
  \#            & a  & D  \\
  & S
  \end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stack it (inside of an `array`).  Here, I use a space as a column separator and set up `@` to be a blank place holder.  I also set up `#` to be `\catcode=12` within the group.

This allows me to set up equations in the top group as

```
\tC{@ # @\\a S #\\@ # @} \rightarrow \tC{@ # @\\a a #\\@ S @}
```

and in the bottom group as

```
S
\Rightarrow\lU{a S\\S @}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a S\\S S @}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,array}
\let\tC\tabbedCenterstack
\let\lU\tabbedLongunderstack
\setstacktabbedgap{.7ex}%
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\stackMath
\setstackTAB{ }%
\begin{document}
\noindent Rewriting rules:
\begin{center}
\bgroup
\extrarowheight=4ex\relax
\catcode`#=12 %
\arraycolsep=1.5em\relax%
\catcode`@=\active %
\def@{}%
$\begin{array}{ccc}
\tC{# #  \\S #  \\# @  } \rightarrow \tC{# #  \\a S  \\S @  } & 
\tC{@ # @\\a S #\\@ # @} \rightarrow \tC{@ # @\\a a #\\@ S @} \\
\tC{@ @ @\\# S S\\@ # @} \rightarrow \tC{@ @ @\\# a D\\@ S @} &
\tC{@ @ @\\a D S\\@ # @} \rightarrow \tC{@ @ @\\a a D\\@ S @} &
\tC{a #  \\D #  \\# @  } \rightarrow \tC{a #  \\a #  \\S @  } \\
\end{array}$
\egroup
\end{center}
\bigskip
A derivation example:
\begin{center}
\bgroup
\extrarowheight=4ex\relax
\catcode`#=12 %
\arraycolsep=1.5em\relax%
\catcode`@=\active %
\def@{}%
$\begin{array}{l}
S
\Rightarrow\lU{a S\\S @}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a S\\S S @}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a S\\S S S @}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\S S S S}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\a D S S\\S @ @ @}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\a a D S\\S S @ @}\\
\phantom{S}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\a a a D\\S S S @}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\a a a a\\S S S S}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\a a a a\\a E S S}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\a a a a\\a a E S}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\a a a a\\a a a E}
\Rightarrow\lU{a a a a\\a a a a\\a a a a}
\end{array}$
\egroup
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]